# search not working on vue-good-table

Tags: vue.js

I'm using `vue-good-table` but I have issue with search. Let me show my code first :

```
<vue-good-table
    mode="remote"

    @on-page-change="onPageChange"
    @on-sort-change="onSortChange"
    @on-column-filter="onColumnFilter"
    @on-per-page-change="onPerPageChange"

    :totalRows="totalRecords"
    pagination-options="{
        enabled: true,
        searchFn: myFunc
    }"
    :searchOptions="{enabled: true}"
    :rows="rows"
    :columns="columns"    
/>
methods:{
    myFunc(row, col, cellValue, searchTerm){
        console.log(searchTerm)
    },
}
```

This method isn't working at all i.e if i remove `mode="remote"` there's still no trigger and another issue with `@on-search`

```
<vue-good-table
    mode="remote"

    @on-page-change="onPageChange"
    @on-sort-change="onSortChange"
    @on-column-filter="onColumnFilter"
    @on-per-page-change="onPerPageChange"

    :totalRows="totalRecords"
    pagination-options="{
        enabled: true,
        searchFn: myFunc
    }"
    :searchOptions="{enabled: true}"
    :rows="rows"
    :columns="columns" 
    @on-search="onSearch"   
/>
methods:{
    onSearch(params) {
       console.log(params) 
    }
}
```

This method works if I remove `mode="remote"` in short both method not get trigger.

Comment: @IdrissNeumann for what reason you give me a negative mark if you don't know the answer then why give negative. if you don't understand my question that means you don't have any ideas about Vue js and vue good table

Comment: I didn't gave you a negative mark! I just formatted your post to give your problem a better chance to be fixed. But If you insist I can give you another negative mark, one of my own this time.

Comment: @IdrissNeumann sorry for blaming you. but this is totally unfair some unknown guys give me negatively without giving me the solution (answer) or reason for giving me negatively... sorry for blaming you

Comment: I agree, at least one person, among others who downvote a message, should give an explanation. Maybe you should formulate a question in your post.

Comment: finally i found my solution it is not working because vue-good-table have bug so upgrade it into 2.8 version issue will be resolve